# Python udp game server freezing

Tags: python, networking, server, pygame, network-programming

I am trying to build a python online game using sockets and udp protocol.
I created a multiprocessing and multithreading server: https://pastebin.com/ZucxWPC9.

```py
import socket
import multiprocess
 
def new_lobby(port, addr1, addr2):
    import socket
    import Queue
    import threading
    address1 = addr1
    address2 = addr2
    local_ip = ""
    local_port = port
    buffer_size = 1024
    print(port)
    sock = socket.socket(family = socket.AF_INET, type = socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((local_ip, local_port))
    sock.settimeout(10)
    running  = True
    q = Queue.Queue(10000)
    print ("before threads")
 
    def listen(sock):
        running = True
        buffer_size = 1024
        while running:
            try:
                data_address = sock.recvfrom(buffer_size)
            except socket.timeout:
                running = False
            q.put(data_address)
    def send(sock, address1, address2):
        while True:
            data_address = q.get()
            if data_address[1] == address1:
                sock.sendto(data_address[0], address2)
            else:
                sock.sendto(data_address[0], address1)
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = listen, args=(sock, ))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target = send, args = (sock, address1, address2))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
 
 
local_ip = ""
local_port = 10001
buffer_size = 1024
 
server_message = "connected"
byte_server_message = str.encode(server_message)
 
sock = socket.socket(family = socket.AF_INET, type = socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 
sock.bind((local_ip, local_port))
 
lobby = []
 
port_count = 10002
 
check_alive = False
 
while True:
    message, address = sock.recvfrom(buffer_size)
    message = message.decode("utf-8")
    print(address, " ", message)
    if address not in lobby:
        lobby.append(address)
    if len(lobby) == 2:
        p = multiprocess.Process(target = new_lobby, args = (port_count,lobby[0], lobby[1]))
        p.start()
        port = str(port_count)
        port = port.encode()
        for address in lobby:
            print(address)
            sock.sendto(port,address)
        port_count += 1
        lobby = []
        check_alive = True
    if check_alive:
        print(p.is_alive())
```

I will explain what the code in there does. So first it's waiting for two requests and puts them in lobby list. If two requests have been made, the server sends  the clients a new port and creates a new process with two threads. Both threads are using the new port , one receiving and the other one is sending the data. I am using a queue so i can keep track of data and avoid using the same resource in the same time.
The client is a pygame game. I made  this small test game of squares moving where the mouse position is. https://pastebin.com/QdKU6Rij.  I have a connection class which i put in init of the game. At first i used multithreading for the connection as well but i observed it was running really slow (i dont think it was threads fault now but i really have no idea). So the curent connection class connects with the main server, waits for a port to be send and starts a new process with two threads: one listening for data and one is sending. I used a queue in there as well even though the multiprocess queue is slow. It was just for test purpose.

```py
import socket
import json
import queue
import threading
import sys
#f = find lobby
pygame.init()
 
class Connection():
    def __init__(self):
        self.msgFromClient = "f"
        self.bytesToSend         = str.encode(self.msgFromClient)
        self.serverAddressPort   = ("", 10001)
        self.bufferSize          = 10000
        self.sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        self.sock.sendto(self.bytesToSend, self.serverAddressPort)
        self.msgFromServer = self.sock.recvfrom(self.bufferSize) 
        self.msg = self.msgFromServer[0]
        self.port = self.msg.decode("utf-8")
        self.port = int(self.port)
        self.serverAddressPort   = ("", self.port)
        self.q_listen = queue.Queue(1000)
        self.q_send = queue.Queue(1000)
        def listen(sock, buffer_size):
            running = True
            while running:
                data_address = sock.recvfrom(buffer_size)
                data = data_address[0].decode("utf-8")
                data = json.loads(data)
                self.q_listen.put(data)
        def send(sock,  serverAddressPort):
            running = True
            while running:
                data = self.q_send.get()
                if data:
                    data = json.dumps(data)
                    data = bytes(data, 'utf-8')
                    sock.sendto(data, serverAddressPort)
 
        sock = self.sock
        buffer_size = self.bufferSize
        serverAddressPort = self.serverAddressPort
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target = listen, args = (sock, buffer_size,))
        self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target = send, args = (sock, serverAddressPort))
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread2.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread2.start()
 
 
 
import global_variables as g
 
#de sters, o sa fie initializat in main game
g.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1800, 900])
 
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = 60
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.size, self.size))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (400, 400)
 
    def Blit(self,screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
 
class Test_Game():
    def __init__(self):
        g.variables_initialization()
        self.surface_size = g.surface_size
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((self.surface_size, self.surface_size))
        self.surface_rect = self.surface.get_rect()
        self.surface_rect.center = (800, 450)
        self.running = True
 
        self.player = Player(g.brown)
        self.player2 = Player(g.green)
        self.connection = Connection()
    
    def Blit_Images(self):
        g.screen.fill(g.white)
        self.surface.fill(g.black)
        self.player.Blit(self.surface)
        self.player2.Blit(self.surface)
        g.screen.blit(self.surface, self.surface_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    def Update(self):
        dt = g.clock.tick(60) / 1000
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.player.rect.centerx = pos[0] - 400
        self.player.rect.centery = pos[1] - 50
        coord = (self.player.rect.centerx, self.player.rect.centery)
        self.connection.q_send.put(coord)
        self.player2.rect.center = self.connection.q_listen.get()
        
            
    
    def Check_Events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            
    def Loop(self):
        while self.running == True:
            self.Check_Events()
            self.Update()
            self.Blit_Images()
 
 
test_game = Test_Game()
test_game.Loop()
```

There is also a file in there for global variables (in case you want to run the code) : https://pastebin.com/RhDwjeKQ

```py
import pygame
def variables_initialization():
    global clock
    global dt
    global screen
    global surface_size
    global white
    global black
    global green
    global brown
    global gray
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    surface_size = 800
    white = (250, 250, 250)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    green = (115, 198, 0)
    brown = (102, 51, 0)
    gray = (215, 218, 218)
```

The problem with this code is that it gets laggy until it completly freezes. At first it works really good but after a few seconds the square looks like it teleports.  My guess is that there might be a memory leak or something i have completly missused, and not really the problem with sending and receiving because my square is laggy too and when the program freezes there so more printing from the update function either. Everything stops.
If you have any idea why this happens I will be  so grateful. I have to finish this project before 30 this month and I am really lost because of this problem. Any advice is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of would be that 2 while loops are running at the same time. Check over your threading and make sure that 2 while loops are not run on the same thread.

Comment: They are running on separate threads. :( I even made a separate process for them to be sure they dont share too much memory with the game but it still freezes